# system IO hangs/freezes randomly for ~30 sec

Tags: 20.04, disk, btrfs

while working on my `ubuntu 20.04` desktop, I'll notice a occasional freezes where it "mostly" goes out to lunch for 10's of seconds to ~1 minute.  Happens perhaps ~~once an hour.  I can still click menus on most programs already open, or switch workspaces (`i3` wm) but launching anything new (including a terminal) hangs, as do many actions in windows.  Combined with the below, it appears that nearly (completely?) all disk IO is hung.

As a result of this, i have been keeping a workspace open with the monitoring tools i'm aware of.  I don't see anything that stands out in `htop`, `NetHogs`, `dmesg` or `journalctl` (specifically with the logs, i'm not noticing any errors or output that happen consistently immediately before I observe the problem).  immediately after (possibly during) a reproduction I do see messages out of processes such as `dockerd` that are consistent with timeouts writing to disk.

`iotop -o` (`-o`=processes actually accomplishing io) output appears to provide good evidence:

- during normal operation, there is a steady rotation of lots of processes, from firefox, through dmcrypt and btrfs workers.
- while reproducing, the list is nearly empty; 2 or 3 processes show up `[kworker/.*events-power-efficient]` and similar.

Some other system information:

- hardware is 6 months old.  I did re-install ubuntu 20.04 a couple months ago, i am *somewhat* confident I did not see this issue immediately after install.
- disks: `/` is btrfs-on-luks on nvme.  Also have a `btrfs` data array, both mounted at boot.  Plenty of room on all drives, `btrfs scrub` shows no errors
- over the (at least week or two?) i've been noticing this I haven't noticed any other system issues.
- `swapon -v` returns `/swap/swapfile file  16G   0B   -2` (system has a lot of memory and is under lite load ATM, so no swap usage isn't surprising)
- doesn't appear to follow a consistent pattern or time, and reproductions vary from two a few minutes apart to perhaps one in 1~2 hours - *however* it's not a given I'll notice all occurances; if I say have am reading a text webpage for several minutes, i believe I might not notice.

I've run a `btrfs scrub` and rebooted several times, and can't see any pattern to when the system locks.  I have backups, haven't seen any corruption, and the system appears to 'resume' without any problems after the system "comes back" - but this is very disconcerting.

How can I gather enough information to help solve this issue?